# How to automatically find the sentiment?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, nlp, nltk

I have written a program that scrapes data from the web and I have in possession about 5k sentences which I want to analyze.

Part 1: I am just starting out in data science and wanted to know if there is such a thing as a library that will read through text and automatically classify words or sentences as being positive/negative/neutral. Is there such a thing that exists, perhaps in R or Python?

Part 2: From what I can tell, there isn't such a library, and I would have to do that myself by hand. It appears that the best way to analyze sentiment is to:

- a) put the words in a corpus
- b) do things like word stemming and
  clean up the text
- c) download a dictionary of predetermined
  sentiment
- d) run a program that vectorizes the text
- e) compare the text from my corpus to the dictionary
- f) ..... unsure what after this step.

Are these steps accurate, or am I totally off-base?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial) is a tutorial, that should help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1: There are pretrained state of the art models trained on their corpus which could be used for [sentiment analysis](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/).

Part 2: You may always train your data on their model rather than creating your own model.